# jquery mobile cache manifest and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am looking into jquery mobile cache manifest and I was wondering if it works with Php files too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, jQuery is a JavaScript based library which is a client-side one. `cache/manifest` is used by HTML(5) which also a client-side language, so long story short: it won't work with PHP.